# How to Check if a Page is Being Requested Programatically?

Tags: php, html, request, server-side

I have a page of my website that shows different content based on the following rules:

if a given cookie is not present then

```
-if referrer is internal then  
--show page 1  
--else  
--show page 2  
else  
-show page 1
```

The problem is, that particular page is occasionally accessed by the server itself (using php in tandem with a PDF API).  Specifically, the code that requests that URL looks like this (and has to look like this):

```
$pdf = $client->convertURI('URL HERE')
```

When that accesses the page, page 2 always shows, because the referrer isn't there, nor is a cookie.

But, I need page 1 to always show...is there a flag or a way to always show page 1 when that particular URL is requested via the server?

Comment: Add the logic to handle that situation -- no cookie, no referer. There isn't any `show page 1` flag that I'm aware of.

Comment: That logic is already there...no cookie, no referrer shows page 2.  But when that page is requested for processing via the PDF api, I need to show page 1...hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you simply want to force the user to a page (page 1) under some condition that you are testing for.  If that is correct, then this should suffice:

```
/** 
   access logic left to your discretion

***/

if ($access != 'granted') 
{
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/page1');
   exit(); // for clarity
}

/******* logic continued for "page 2" or whatever *****/
```

Comment: just to be clear there isn't anything magic about the variable "$access" or the value 'granted'. You will modify that to suite your needs.

Comment: That's where the problem is though.  If there is no cookie, and the referrer isn't internal or doesn't exist, I need to show the user page 2.  It just so happens those same exact conditions exist when requesting that page for processing for the PDF API, which is why I was wondering if there was any extra "condition" that requesting a URL programatically presents.

Comment: So you're asking how to get around a required cookie?  Your server can't tell who is on the other side.  It's just an HTTP request (via a browser or otherwise).  Can you reverse your logic?  Add a flag (condition) that triggers the PDF API - when not present go to Page 2 instead....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution, partly due to "ChronoFish's" comment of "can you reverse your logic"...although not directly.

The solution I came up with, is very simple, and I'm mad I didn't think of it before.

Alright, site works like this:

User visits URL 1  - on URL 1, if a user has no given cookie present and their referrer is not internal or is blank, they are shown URL 2.  If a user arriving at URL 1 has a given cookie present or their referrer is internal, they are shown URL 1.  This is all in my original question.

The problem I was having, was that a PDF API also requests URL 1, and a server side call like that has no cookie or referrer...so the PDF API was having content from URL 2 returned to it instead of the content from URL 1 which is what was needed.

How the PDF API was called, was using this:

```
$pdf = $client->convertURI('URL 1 HERE')
```

Well, all I did was add a variable to the URL so where URL 1 here is, the URL now reads like this:

```
http://somesite.com/URL-1/?server=yes
```

Then, on URL 1, I added an additional bit of logic:

```
$server = $_GET["server"];
if ($server == 'yes')
then show URL 1
```

And then the rest of my original code within an additional else statement.